# Возможно ли иметь 2 счёта на аккаунте разработчика ITunes Connect

Tags: apple

Добрый день! Возможно кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой: у компании несколько приложений с платным контентом на одном аккаунте разработчика.
Одно из них перешло к другой организации, но деньги с покупок пользователей продолжают поступать на общий счёт прошлой компании.
Вопрос: можно ли создать на данном аккаунте разработчика ещё один счёт, чтоб деньги с покупок в этом приложении приходили на него?
Заранее благодарю!